# How to automatically turn on hotspot?

Tags: debian, gnome, wifi-hotspot

Gnome desktop on Debian Jessie provides easy interface to use WiFi on the laptop and turn it into a hotspot. Is there a way to make it do automatically at startup or can I create a "shortcut" for that?

Answer (score 9):

Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot` and change the line

```
autoconnect=false
```

to

```
autoconnect=true
```

Comment: currently working for Ubuntu 18.04