# How to route all the traffic from wlan0 to eth0 and making ip given to wlan0 act as a gateway?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have 2 laptops both connected on the same LAN using wifi . In One laptop I have working internet connection which i shared to laptop 2 using Ethernet , as i wanted to create a new gateway on the same LAN , so that clients connected to LAN via my gateway have an access to the internet .

The internet sharing via ethernet is working on laptop 2 and for the ethernet interface and the ip configuration are as

```
eth0
Connection mode - Shared to other Computers
IP - 192.168.137.2
Subnet -24
Gateway - 192.168.137.1
DNS - 8.8.8.8 ,4.4.4.4
```

The ip configuration of wireless interface wlan0 on the same compute are as follows (This interface will act as gateway )

```
wlan0
Connection mode - Manual
IP - 192.168.144.111
Subnet -24
Gateway - EMPTY
DNS - EMPTY
```

The clients connected on the same network have ip configuaration as

```
interface - eth0/wlan0
Connection mode - Manual
IP - 192.168.144.X
Subnet -24
Gateway - 192.168.144.111
DNS - 8.8.8.8 ,4.4.4.4
```

I have enabled ip_forwarding in my linux pc but clients connected to same subnet are not able to connect to the internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically turn on hotspot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183981/how-to-automatically-turn-on-hotspot)

Comment: *Rewritten the problem

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to enable `ip_forwarding`:

`echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Set a default route out of `eth0`:

`ip route add default via 192.168.137.1`

Then tell clients on the `wlan0` LAN to use `192.168.144.111` as their gateway. If you control the `dhcp` server, change your gateway in the `dhcp` config.

You'll probably need to set up `NAT` as well, if you want clients on `192.168.144.0/24` to connect to the internet:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

Comment: Still not working
Error On Client Sides
"err name not resolved"

what should be my defalut gateway address for my wlan0
and DNS address.

Comment: Clients on the `wlan0` LAN should use the IP address on the `wlan0` interface of your linux machine as the default gateway, so `192.168.144.111`.

Comment: `"err name not resolved"` - your clients can't reach a DNS server, you could set their DNS to `8.8.8.8` (or to whatever your linux machine is using as it's DNS server), which would then be routed via the default gateway and natted when it comes out of the `eth0` interface.